# Gap detection - MS Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in my `Microsoft SQL` server, both have serial numbers in their data looks like this (basically one has serials with an incrementing alpha at the end and the other is just numerical):

**Table One**

- 1234567A
- 1234568A
- 1234569A

**Table Two**

- 1234567
- 1234568
- 1234569

Is there a function in `Microsoft SQL` server to identify gaps in the serialized data?

**Example:**

If there is a serial number for `1234569` and `1234570` does not exist in the data set, I would like that identified.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify gaps using `not exists` for the *numeric* values:

```
select t2
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 tt2
                  where tt2.serial = t2.serial + 1
                 );
```

This will always return the last row in the table.